# Slide Toggle nested ordered list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create a vertical menu where the sub-items (nested in another ordered list) are shown/hidden every time the main list item is pressed. I'm running into two issues:

1. Works in JSFiddle, but not on my local folder.
     *- file Jquery.js placed in folder "js" and src="js/Jquery.js"**
2. The slide-toggle behavior of the 2nd menu "header" isn't quite the same as the first "header". It is more of a toggle than a slideToggle - why is that?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chg9w/225/

```
<ol class="main_menu">
   <li class="main_item">
      <a href="#">Profile</a>
   </li>
   <ol>
      <li class="sub_item"><a href="#">details</a></li>
      <li class="sub_item"><a href="#">uploaded CV</a></li>
   </ol>

   <li class="main_item_last"><a href="#">Applied Jobs</a></li>
   <ol>        
      <li class="sub_item"><a href="#">In-progress</a></li>    
      <li class="sub_item"><a href="#">Completed</a></li>    
   </ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: I doubt `ol` is a valid child element of `ol`. Do you know for sure that this is allowed in your doctype?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Basically I reused some jQuery code meant for unordered lists and adapted it to this. Is there a better way to mimic the mentioned behavior?

Comment: I'll show you a demo, let me just fix your CSS - HTML

Answer (score 0):

Just add this on your css to be fixed. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chg9w/231/)

```
ol li {
 overflow:hidden;   
}​
```