# Nested ordered toggled list, non repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, toggle

I am coding a dichotomous key: an ordered, toggled list with two options to choose from at each level. The nested items cannot repeat numbers later, but increase in numbering. The numbers need 'a' and 'b' appended:

> 1a.
>
> > 2a.
> >
> > > 3a.
> > >
> > > 3b.
> >
> > 2b.
> >
> > > 4a.
> > >
> > > 4b.
>
> 1b.
>
> > 5a.
> >
> > > 6a.
> > >
> > > 6b.
> >
> > 5b.
> >
> > > 7a.
> > >
> > > 7b.

Basic HTML ordered list:

```
<ol>
  <li>1a
    <ol>
      <li>2a
    <ol>
      <li>3a</li>
      <li>3b</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>2b
    <ol>
      <li>4a</li>
      <li>4b</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

```
<ol>
  <li>1b
    <ol>
      <li>3a
    <ol>
      <li>5a</li>
      <li>5b</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>2b
    <ol>
      <li>6a</li>
      <li>6b</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The nested items need to toggle visibility, which can be done with JQuery and display:none DIVs, but is there a way to avoid DIVs? Unless each listed item is automatically placed inside a DIV, the key is too large to hand number with "1a", "1b."

JQuery toggling:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
$("#"+divId).toggle();
}
</script>
```

The accompanying CSS:

```
.display {display:none;
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

What mix of JQuery and CSS countering do I need to get the nested items to pick up numbering where it left off, not restart it? The nesting needs to go to unlimited levels deep, while never repeating numbers anywhere in the list.

How can I adapt the following CSS to add letters, not decimal numbers?:

```
   <style>
        html>/**/body ol { /* Won't be interpreted by IE6/7. */
            list-style-type: none;
            counter-reset: level1;
        }
        ol li:before {
            content: counter(level1) ". ";
            counter-increment: level1;
        }
        ol li ol {
            list-style-type: none;
            counter-reset: level2;
        }
        ol li ol li:before {
            content: counter(level1) "." counter(level2) " ";
            counter-increment: level2;
        }
        ol li span { /* For IE6/7. */
            margin: 0 5px 0 -25px;
        }
    </style>
```

Questions on nested lists, or changing numbering style, have been asked, but I can't find one with this non-repeating numbering, with toggled options. See- [Nested ordered lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852816/nested-ordered-lists) and [Slide Toggle nested ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988559/slide-toggle-nested-ordered-list)

Comment: Why would you want to avoid divs? Or do you have other elements that could make the divs superfluous? Please show us your markup as well.

Comment: With DIVs I can get the look of a nested list, with indent, but I need a proper ordered list with numbering that does not repeat. I added the JQuery and CSS I do have.

Comment: What CSS do you currently use for the numbering? And again, please show us your HTML markup.

Comment: I added the HTML for an ordered list, and CSS countering that has been shared before, but how can I add letters? Can CSS provide non-repeating numbers? Thanks for your help; this question is getting bulky.

Comment: Thanks for the markup, I'm gonna write an answer. Btw, you forgot to close some `<ol>`s on the second level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What mix of JQuery and CSS countering do I need to get the nested items to pick up numbering where it left off, not restart it?

[CSS counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters) are not capable of doing that.

You can reset them to zero on a new nesting level which does scope them - but then they're not continous ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTUze/1/)). You can initialise them only once, but then they're not reset for the higher-level items ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTUze/2/)). With something like that, you can even enumerate the first and the innermost items as desired - but still not for b-items ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTUze/5/)).

It only might be possible to do some clever counter mathematics if you know that each list has exactly 2 children and your depth is fixed - I guess you'd need a separate counter for each level then as well. Indeed it's possible:

```css
/* The counter styles only - no list styles, not the ab-counter
Should be coded in SASS/LESS, it's no fun to do by hand :-)
Here are the rules, on an example with 4 levels max: */


/* each ol increases the counters for its and lower levels */
         ol { counter-increment: level0 level1 level2 level3; }
      ol ol { counter-increment:        level1 level2 level3; }
   ol ol ol { counter-increment:               level2 level3; }
ol ol ol ol { counter-increment:                      level3; }

/* the ol in the last list item of a level should also advance the above level
   by the number of ols inside its parent list */
      li:last-child > ol { counter-increment: level0 14 level1 level2 level3; }
   li li:last-child > ol { counter-increment: level1 6         level2 level3; }
li li li:last-child > ol { counter-increment: level2 2                level3; }
/*                                                   ^
            The number can be computed as 2 ^ (max - level) - 2
              in here: 14 = 2^4-2; 6 = 2^3-2; 2 = 2^2-2
   The extra rule on the first level can actually be omitted */

/* And each li should use the counter for its level */
         li:before { content: counter(level0)" "; }
      li li:before { content: counter(level1)" "; }
   li li li:before { content: counter(level2)" "; }
li li li li:before { content: counter(level3)" "; }
```

([Demo for 3 levels](http://jsfiddle.net/tTUze/9/), [Demo for 4 levels](http://jsfiddle.net/tTUze/8))

> How can I adapt the counter CSS to add letters, not decimal numbers?

You can pass a list-style-type as the second argument to the counter function ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counter-styles)):

```
content: counter(level1) counter(level2, lower-latin) " ";
```

Comment: Thank you Bergi. I am considering my predicament and may have to scrap CSS counters altogether, unless I can find a mathematician to formally define this pattern of numbering.

Comment: WOW thank you! I'm going to try to take this to 9 or 10 nested levels. If I can't get it, I'll come back here. If I do get it, I'll post what I have anyway. :)

Comment: So I got the nesting to 5 levels, but it looks like the CSS expects there to be a balanced number of children for every parent - something occupying every level. The numbering skips to higher numbers. http://jsfiddle.net/q7qTR/3/

Comment: Yes, I expected the depth to be fixed. Otherwise it's impossible to know how many `ol`s there were above your parent `ol` in the second `li`. I guess one would need to initialize counters with values of other counters… which is impossible in CSS. I fear you're left to manual numbering.